# Refresh directive when root scope property changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which generates a random number. I want to refresh or reload this directive when checkbox is toggled.
I have following code and it's not working for me

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.updateTemplate = function() {
   $rootScope.$broadcast('refresh');
  }
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
   $scope.$on('refresh', function (event) {
     alert("refreshing");
     if ($scope.refresh == 'false') {
       $scope.refresh = 'true';
     } else {
       $scope.refresh = 'false';
     }
   })
});

app.directive('myElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {
      refresh : '='
    },
      template: "<div> Hello World </div>" + Math.random()
  }
})
```

here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/hAPqGoltoZELJ2Cva2sN?p=preview

Comment: Use an event with $broadcast and $on, not a data property!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS directive templates are compiled and inserted into the DOM with markers that Angular then uses to do the things like data binding. This happens *once*, when the directive is first encountered in the DOM (well, assuming you don't have modifiers like ngIf which can change that.)

You are inserting the value of the random function at the time you call it. Since the template is never re-evaluated Angular doesn't know that it isn't just static text. Just adjust your code so that you have a link function that sets a scope variable, and use that in an expression:

```
template: "<div> Hello World </div> {{ randomValue }}",
  link: function($scope) {
     function doRefresh() {
       $scope.randomValue = Math.random();
   }

   $scope.$on('refresh', doRefresh);
   doRefresh();
  }
```

Working Plunkr here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/VIJiJx2AuktyDgPiyCCu?p=preview